# Store a OBject value and update the Value if it changes in MVC3 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, entity-framework-4, session-state

I need to implement the Functionality where User Object (which contains some other Navigation properties ) is stored when anyone log in

i want to Access this information when fetching information related to User so that i need not hit the Database for example

User has Announcements so if i have to query for that i want like this

```
    Announcements announcements = Storage.User.Announcements;
    var result = from m in announcements 
                 where m.DueDate== 'someting'
```

i have lots of functionalities associated with User and want to Persists and Query the records without getting from DB

When User Log' out the Value from Storage.User should clean up

i have implemented the Singleton Pattern but its not working

PLs suggest any Pattern or practice

Answer (score 0):

Singletone will not work here because whenever a new request is made, your controllers (and objects generated by controller) are regenerated. HTTP does not keep the state, remember.

To persist, you may store the object in session.

When logging in, do:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["the-session-key"] = YourObject
```

When you need to access the Object, do:

```
YourObjectType yourObject = (YourObjectType)HttpContext.Current.Session["the-session-key"]
```

To clear the Session, do:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
```

If you are doing it inside the controller, you may directly access the `Session` with `Session` property in the controller.

For example, in a Controller, you may do:

```
Session.Clear()
```